# Convert Msol Powershell to Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, multi-factor-authentication

I need some help with Azure powershell as i know very little about powershell,Any help would be much appreciated. (this will be used in Azure Runbook check for people who register for MFA and add them to a group for conditional access)

I would like to convert this Msol Powershell script to Azure powershell

```
#get group
$group = get-msolgroup - <groupIDnumber>

#get all users with stronge authentication 
$users = get-msoluser -all | select userprincipalname,objectid,StrongAuthenticationMethods
  | where {$_.StrongAuthenticationMethods -ne $null}

#add users to group
$users | foreach {
    add-msolgroupmember -groupobjectid $group.objectid -groupmembertype "user" -groupmemberobjectid $_.objectid
}
```

So far i have

```
$group = get-AzureADgroup -objectid <groupidnumber>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the commands in the latest AzureAD module.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/

I believe the cmdlet structure are the same you just need to change `msol` with `AzureAD`

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, there's no way to get the StrongAuthenticationMethods property (or its equivalent) with the AzureAD cmdlets.  There's a long standing request to add this:  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20249953-powershell-and-graph-api-support-for-managing-mult?page=1&per_page=20

You can get a user's authentication methods from the Microsoft Graph API at [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}/authentication/methods](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7Bid%7D/authentication/methods). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authenticationmethod?view=graph-rest-beta

But if really you just want to add these users to a conditional access group, can you just create a conditional access policy instead?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa

Comment: yea but they can only be added to the policy once they have been registered for MFA. i just have the script running on prem its not ideal but it works. we have the old MFA setup before you couldnt block where the registration can take place from